# How do I select one of two imported models?

Tags: mesh, objects

I have two OBJ files.  I Imported the first, then imported the second right after.  When I try to do a shift-drag select on the second model, the first one gets highlighted as well.  Shift drag select doesn't even work on the first model.  How do I select the second only so I can move it next to the other?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by "shift drag select". I'm not familiar with this kind of selecting. You select an object by right-clicking it. Or - if you use Blender 2.80 (another missing piece of important information) - you left-click on it, depending on your settings. You drag an object by pushing 'G' on your keyboard.

Comment: Apologies, I'll include the version number on any subsequent posts I make.  And thank you for the response.  I actually just rebooted my system and when i got it back up, it was working fine.  Appreciate the time.

Answer (score 0):

rebooted my system and when i got it back up, it was working fine.